# Encontrar código que se ejecuta al oprimir un botón

Tags: android-studio, servidor, actionbar, depuración

cordial saludo.

Revisando el siguiente código de la App https://github.com/symph-team/mobile-android-survey-app

He intentado en Android Studio 3.1.4 realizar una depuración del sistema, pero al ejecutar el código en el emulador y dar click en el botón de continuar (flecha en el action bar), de una lanza un msgbox que indica "Username Required -  Please enter your username"...dejo la imagen de la ventana de login en cuestión de ejemplo. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symph-team/mobile-android-survey-app/master/doc/1.0/armm_login.png

He buscado dentro del código hasta el msg de error en los modulos java y en los string pero no lo encuentro.  Deseo saber como lograr llegar al modulo que hace el login con el servidor para poder modificarlo y que ubique la base de datos de modo local, puede alguien ayudarme a encontrar el código de conexión al server?

Gracias

Comment: El codigo del boton se encuentra en la clase [LoginFragment](https://github.com/symph-team/mobile-android-survey-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/worldbank/armm/app/fragments/LoginFragment.java) Linea 43, ahí empieza la validación de los campos.  Este se encuentra en la carpeta `fragments` del proyecto.. La clase que se encarga de enviar la petición al Api es [LoginUser](https://github.com/symph-team/mobile-android-survey-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/worldbank/armm/app/tasks/LoginUser.java) que se encuentra en la carpeta `tasks` del proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a revisar de inmediato...espero lograr a futuro tener tu dominio del lenguaje y la herramienta.

Comment: @Andrespengineer, tu en la revisión observaste en que módulo se da la URL de conexión, que me indiques por favor?

Comment: El codigo del login esta en el paquete **Fragment -> LoginFragment.class** linea 43 se ejecuta el boton del menu para el inicio de sesion. La clase de inicio de sesion esta en la clase **Task -> LoginUser.class** La URL de conexion se inicializa en la clase **Application.class** linea 20 y la URL se obtiene del **AndroidManifest** linea 36. Para ser mas exactos la URL de login es: http://opened.urls.ph/api/v1/user/login

Comment: @KenjiKawaidaVillegas mis mas sinceros agradecimientos por tu ayuda.